# Self contained web-based (ASP.NET) gallery viewer

Tags: asp.net, image-gallery

I need to add a gallery to my website, to show screen shots of websites and applications.

I run IIS.

I'm looking for something that is fairly self-contained and ready to integrate without a lot of work. I'd like to through a bunch of images in a directory and let it go.

I would love some nice effects for browsing the gallery.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [nGallery](http://chrison.net/nGalleryUpdatedForASPNET20.aspx) for ASP.NET 2.0.  I've support an application that uses an older version of this.  No experience with this particular version, though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Gallery Server Pro ([www.galleryserverpro.com](http://www.galleryserverpro.com)). It is a free open source web gallery based on ASP.NET and has been around for several years. It is easy to integrate into an existing site by using the self-contained ascx user control.

Disclaimer: I am the Creator and Lead Developer.